# With TikZiT 0.8.398 for Mac OS, can I use custom shapes as nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say that I want to use the "pants" shape in a diagram, like so

[image: my diagram]

The TikZ code generated is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=pants] (0) at (0, 0) {};
        \node [style=none] (1) at (1, -1) {};
        \node [style=none] (2) at (-1, -1) {};
        \node [style=none] (3) at (0, 1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [bend right, looseness=4.75] (2.center) to (0);
        \draw [bend right, looseness=0.75] (1.center) to (0);
        \draw (3.center) to (0);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where my pants node is simply invocated with `style=pants`. This isn't going to fly, so I need to have this style in the preamble of my document. TikZiT provides a preamble, but when I click `Insert node styles to selected preamble`, no declaration of the pants style appears.

There is, however, a generated definition of the pants style as a tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=none] (0) at (-0.5, 1) {};
        \node [style=none] (1) at (0.5, 1) {};
        \node [style=none] (2) at (-1.5, -1) {};
        \node [style=none] (3) at (-0.5, -1) {};
        \node [style=none] (4) at (0.5, -1) {};
        \node [style=none] (5) at (1.5, -1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [in=90, out=90, looseness=1.75] (4.center) to (3.center);
        \draw [in=-90, out=90, looseness=0.75] (2.center) to (0.center);
        \draw [in=-90, out=-90, looseness=0.75] (0.center) to (1.center);
        \draw [in=90, out=-90, looseness=0.75] (1.center) to (5.center);
        \draw [in=90, out=90, looseness=0.75] (5.center) to (4.center);
        \draw [in=90, out=90, looseness=0.75] (3.center) to (2.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I would want, ideally, is that TikZiT itself would insert the correct definitions into my preamble. But this doesn't seem to happen. Can I still use the code available to get this diagram working?